# Importing to UE4 without smoothing?

Tags: export

I have a model I'd like to export to UE4 but I'm going for a low poly "look" and want to keep the jagged and blocky look it has. Is there a way for me to export it into UE4 without the smoothing effects?

Comment: The approach may depend on the format you're using for the export. Have you tried marking all edges as sharp in edit mode (CTRL + E > Mark Sharp)? If that doesn't work the edge split modifier will likely work.

Comment: Firstly, you can follow LuckyCOINNNN's insttuction or go to the data tab of the object and enable auto smooth and set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to change the import setting on normals to import Tangent and Normals. [image]

Comment: Ahhh... that'll do it... wierd though as the importer usually defaults to that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, follow LuckyCOINNNN's suggestion (although I wouldn't recommend using the split edge modifier, as it will separate all your edge verts), or go to the data tab of the object and enable Auto Smooth with a value of 0 (if you are doing this method you must select all faces and set to shade smooth first), or you can select all faces/verts/edges and set to Shade Flat.

Secondly if you're using FBX to export to UE4, in the Geometry section of the exporter set Smooth to Edge (I think Face also works).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can't seem to find the Auto Smooth option in the data tab.

Comment: I modified my answer with a pic for ya :-D

Comment: Thank you. As it turns out, that option isn't selected. Strangely enough on a recent model I just made, importing THAT one to UE4 doesn't auto-smooth it, but the original one still does. I must have ticked some box somewhere that made it do this. But the only difference that comes to mind now is that the model that is auto-smoothing has a full armature with rig and animations, but I don't believe that would make it smooth.

Comment: It won't apply the auto smooth if you don't  set all the models poly's to Shade Smooth (Edit mode/ select all/ ctrl-f/ select Shade Smooth about 2/3rds the way down)... It sounds to me like that step may have been missing on the model that wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it still imports smoothly whether the shade is set to flat or smooth.

Comment: Because you have to set the fbx export, under the Geometry section, you have to set Smooth to Edge (I THINK face works as well)